# bash read command

Tags: bash, shell

I try to use read command to catch what user enters.

```
read -p "Please enter your name -> " -n 20 name
```

But I figured out that we can't rectify what we have entered. How can I make the "BackSpace" remove and not add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `-e` flag to read, which will make it use readline.

```
read -e -p "Please enter your name -> " -n 20 name
```

You could also change your terminal settings (stty) so that backspace instead of delete is erase.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the text entered by the user (or any other text) through `col -b`, for example:

```
name=`echo $name|col -b`
```

This is more portable than using option `-e` of the `read` command, because `-e` is not supported on all Unix systems, for example AIX (I think it is a GNU/Linux extension).